# How to load and process HTML from Ajax request

Tags: java, android, ajax, dom-manipulation

I'd like to run a background task in my android app which sends an Ajax request, parses/manipulates the HTML from the response and creates a new object from the HTML data.

It is very easy to request and manipulate the data and create new object (without multithreading). I can create a WebView, load a local HTML file with some JavaScript functions, send an Ajax request from the JavaScript, manipulate it with jQuery and send it back via 'MyJavaScriptInterface'.

### Java Code Snippet

```
// method of 'MyJavaScriptInterface'
public void processJSON(String jsonArrayString) {
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
            // MyObject obj = new MyObject(row.getString("title"),
            //                             row.getString("href")  );
            // do something fancy with the object
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("MyJavaScriptInterface", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

// initialize WebView
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "android");

// load local html file with JavaScript functions
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

### JavaScript Code Snippet

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/index',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find('#container').children().each(function(){

            jsonArray.push( {
                'title': this.title, 
                'href': this.href
            } )
        });

        jsonArray = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
        // send 'jsonArray' back to the android device
        android.processJSON( jsonArray );
    }
});
```

### HTML Code Snippet:

This is what the website looks like - but I have no control over the content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- header -->
    [...]
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <a href="someUrl" title="someTitle"><img src="relativeImageUrl"></a>
                <!-- more links -->
                [...]
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to load the data in a separate thread but this is not possible with a WebView, so here are my questions:

## Questions

- How should I perform the same task **without** jQuery and JavaScript?
- Is there an easy way to access the DOM in Java (or do i have to parse the whole XML structure of the HTML data)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it looks like you are receiving json, not html. hence i don't see to dom part.

Comment: I receive html in the JavaScript Code Snippet:
`$(data).find('#container').children().each(function()`

... I will add a snippet of the HTML file

Comment: just to make it clear, you make a request to a server, the server formats a nice html page, you receive it, you parse the html page and turn it into json ?

Comment: can't you, like, simplify that and ask the server to give you json in the first place?

Comment: The website seems to have been built with php, so i can't find any server interface which serves something other than plain text/html.